# Can I downcast in Swift in a "for in" control structure?

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I have a sorted array of details generated from an NSSet.  I want to iterate through them to print them out.  Right now I do this:

```
    for aDetail in sortedDetails! {
        let someDetail = aDetail as! Detail
        if someDetail.parentDetail != "" {
            print("----\(someDetail.name)")
        } else {
            print("\(someDetail.name)")
        }
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do the "let someDetail = aDetail as! Detail" in the "for-in" definition instead?  (i.e. Force the downcast in the definition of the for-in loop rather than create a separate variable that's cast?)

This works but it feels clunky.

Comment: @iosDev82 No, but you *can* cast the array (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array's contents are guaranteed to be convertible to `Detail`, you can cast the array:

```
for aDetail in sortedDetails as! [Detail] {
    if aDetail.parentDetail != "" {
        print("----\(aDetail.name)")
    } else {
        print("\(aDetail.name)")
    }
}
```